# Write array in file

Tags: matlab, file

I need to export two arrays A and B in a text file, the values in A and B must be separated by spaces (so it is readable like when A and B are printed in the console).
A and B contain integers and floats.

I tried fprintf, but it has no effect (and no error message):

```
 fid2=fopen('file0','w');
 fprintf(fid2,'%f %f %f',A);
 fprintf(fid2,'%d %d %d',B);
 fclose(fid2);
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. I find it very hard to believe you followed the example in the [documentation for `fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf98f7) and got nothing.

Comment: What does `fprintf` return? Is `fid2` a positive number?

Comment: fid2=20 and fprintf returns 803 and 192.

Comment: This indicates that the file is successfully opened (fid > 2) and the 803 and 192 are the bytes written to the file. My guess is that you are writing to another directory than you are expecting. Check `pwd`, it tells you the current working directory.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, my mistake, the current directory was not the one containing the file.

Comment: Voting to close this as it's due to a simple error of you not checking the correct directory of where your output file is located.

Comment: Yes, but the answear below can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another function you could use, called dlmwrite()

The code would look like:

```
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',A,           'delimiter', ' ' ,'precision','%f');
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',B,'-append', 'delimiter', ' ' ,'precision','%d');
```

No fopen, fid and fclose needed.